# mysql id (auto_increment ) related query

Tags: mysql

I have about 14000 rows added through a script with ID ( auto_increment ) in mysql database.

then I added row with ID number 99999 manually , now when i add a row with script  it adds after 99999 inspite of deleting the row with ID 99999 .

How do i continue from row number 140001 ?

Cheers,

Comment: This is not advisable because it might lead to a problem when your auto increment is grow to 99998.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good database management tool will have support for that.

If you need to do it in SQL, use this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=14001;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the auto incrment which is part of the table def. Note if you do this and there is a collision weird things will happen. Eg you set its back to 12.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=14001;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 140001
```

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/reset-auto-increment-value-mysql/